# In python, repeat a 2d array different amount of times

Tags: python, loops, repeat

I am working in python. I have an array `stud` with shape `(3, 11, 16)` and another array `times = np.array[740, 560, 600]`. I want to repeat the first slice of `a` (`0 ,11 ,16`) 740 times. Then I want to repeat the next slice of `a` `(1, 11, 16)` 560 times and the same with the third slice.

This is my attempt

```
new_array = []
for i in times:
    for j in range(len(stud)):
        rep = np.repeat(stud[j,:,:], i, axis=0)
```

The problem here is that all slices `j` is repeated `i` times. I want to make it work so that, for the first `i` then only the first `j` is executed. For the second `i` only the second `j` is executed and so forth. 
Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: new_array.append(rep) should not be there. I'm sorry for this confusion

Comment: you can edit your question to remove the extra line

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is :

```
new_array = []
for i, j in zip(times, range(len(stud))):
    rep = np.repeat(stud[j,:,:], i, axis=0)
```

This will go through the loop 3 times:

First time, `i=740, j=0`

Second time, `i=560, j=1`

Third time, `i=600, j=2`

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes you are completely right. When I am doing this I am getting an error:TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
I think that this is due to that times is an array but len(stud) is an integer

Comment: Yes, its just above your comment.

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer by adding `range()`. Try it out

Comment: This does not give me the correct shape for the outcome. Shape of times is (324, 11, 16) and shape of stud is (324). Shape of outcome is (8184, 16). This should end up being a 3D array. Here I cannot figure out what went wrong.

Comment: you mean the other way around right? shape of stud is (324,11,16) and shape of times is (324,) ? Otherwise it contradicts the example in your question

Comment: `new = []
for i, j in zip(rough_off, range(len(rough))):
hej = np.tile(rough[j,:,:], (i,1,1))
new.append(hej)`

Comment: Above is the solution. I used np.tile instead. Sorry the mess, but i do not know how to type coding in comments.